# Pepper emulator not start because INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, robotics, pepper

I can't run my app by Pepper's emulator because from the log it tells me that there is not sufficient space in the emulator.

`Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE  List of apks: \[0\] 'C:\\Users\\aless\\AndroidStudioProjects\\TestPepper\\app\\build\\intermediates\\apk\\debug\\app-debug.apk' The device needs more free storage to install the application (extra space is needed in addition to APK size). Retry Failed to launch an application on all devices`

I have already reset the emulator to factory data but it keeps telling me there is no space.

How can i increase the space since in the Device Manager it doesn't show me the emulator?

Thank you very much

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLuro.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MmCH.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1k2V.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tifsB.png)

Comment: Setup another device and see if it still does it.. I never use emulator, I always use a physical device. For the exact same reason as the issue you are having